# Nomenclature sorting and latex code coming first

Tags: symbols, lyx, sorting, nomenclature

I am using `LyX`, which uses `Nomenclature` package, I guess. As you see in the screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e06z2.png), `\hat{p}` comes before everything else. How can I send it back where the other `p`'s are?

Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: It seems I have to give up on this, since I usually get an answer in few minutes here :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the optional prefix argument for fine-tuning sorting, such as

```
\nomenclature[p]{$\hat{p}$}{Kinematik pressure}
```

Comment: What if I have already a [sort code defined](http://pastebin.com/Ldqv82kA). The outcomes is that "p" sorting ends up in Greek letters for me.

Comment: and many thanks by the way. I thought nobody knew the answer.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you got a solution?

Comment: @Anand I believe [this solves the problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112894/3965)