# Sorting the nomenclature description

Tags: sorting, nomenclature

I am using nomencl package to prepare the nomenclature for my thesis. In that, the package sorts the symbols as shown in Figure.

[image: symbol_sorted]

But I want the desription of the symbols in Right hand side to be sorted in alphabetical order without using prefix option as shown in Figure.

[image: Desription_sorted]

using of prefix option work consumes lot of time and manual effort. Kindly suggest solution.

**MWE code:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
\nomenclature{$\omega$}{Absolute Frequency}
\nomenclature{HOA}{Acetic acid}
\nomenclature{Al}{Aluminium}
\nomenclature{ASTM}{American Standard Testing Machine}
\printnomenclature
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{thesis}
\bibliography{refpapers}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg Added a MWE code.

Comment: @egreg Please note that the desription of the symbols are to be sorted. It was not the case in [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23508/nomenclature-sorting-and-latex-code-coming-first].

Comment: Would `\newcommand\Nomenclature[2]{\nomenclature[#2]{#1}{#2}}` and then using `\Nomenclature` instead of `\nomenclature` work for you?

Comment: @cgnieder thanks. It works fine and as expected.

Comment: @cgnieder The question is reopened. Please post your comment as solution. The solution perfectly works. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per request to turn my comment into an answer: you could define a command

```
\newcommand\Nomenclature[2]{\nomenclature[#2]{#1}{#2}}
```

that automatically inserts the description to the optional sorting argument of `\nomenclature` and then use it instead of `nomenclature`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\newcommand\Nomenclature[2]{\nomenclature[#2]{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
Text% to produce a non-empty page

\Nomenclature{$\omega$}{Absolute Frequency}
\Nomenclature{HOA}{Acetic acid}
\Nomenclature{Al}{Aluminium}
\Nomenclature{ASTM}{American Standard Testing Machine}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

[image]