# Make nomenclature sort math correctly

Tags: sorting, nomenclature

I am sorting my nomenclature as suggested by the `nomencl` package documentation, but `\dot{q}` is being sorted before `a` and `v`, where as the desired sort is:

- `a`
- `\dot{q}`
- `v`

The existence of a default prefix does not help, so `noprefix` is used. Prefixes are used to separate Roman `[1]` from Greek `[2]` variables.

```
\documentclass[oneside,paper=a4,fontsize=12pt,english]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[noprefix]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
\printnomenclature
\nomenclature[1]{\(a\)}{Semimajor axis}
\nomenclature[1]{\(v\)}{Velocity}
\nomenclature[1]{\(\dot{q}\)}{Heat flux}
\nomenclature[2]{\(\rho\)}{Density}
% makeindex.exe Test.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o Test.nls
Lorem ipsum.
\end{document}
```

Using `[1q]` as a prefix causes `\dot{q}` to be sorted at the end of the Roman variables. How can I get `nomenclature` to ignore `\dot{}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent symbols from being sorted by surrounding commands, such as `\dot{q}`, append the prefix with the math mode of the symbol without any additional commands like so:

```
\nomenclature[1\(q\)]{\(\dot{q}\)}{Heat flux}
```

In the full example we see that this additional syntax is only required for the single problem variable:

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[oneside,paper=a4,fontsize=12pt,english]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[noprefix]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
    \printnomenclature
    \nomenclature[1]{\(a\)}{Semimajor axis}
    \nomenclature[1]{\(v\)}{Velocity}
    \nomenclature[1\(q\)]{\(\dot{q}\)}{Heat flux}
    \nomenclature[2]{\(\rho\)}{Density}
    % makeindex.exe Test.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o Test.nls
    Lorem ipsum.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

Just add to *all* the entries that have math an ASCII version for sorting:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[oneside,paper=a4,fontsize=12pt,english]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[noprefix]{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

\printnomenclature
\nomenclature[1a]{\(a\)}{Semimajor axis}
\nomenclature[1v]{\(v\)}{Velocity}
\nomenclature[1q]{\(\dot{q}\)}{Heat flux}
\nomenclature[2rho]{\(\rho\)}{Density}

Lorem ipsum.
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `arara` you don't need to remember the command for producing the `.nls` file. :)

Comment: That works thanks, but it made me try `\nomenclature[1\(q\)]{\(\dot{q}\)}{Heat flux}` which works without changing all the others. I'm writing a dissertation so only changing this one entry is ideal. I'm not sure if you should edit your answer with this solution?

Comment: Take care if you have more then 9 entries, you should use leading zeros to get the sorting right, e.g., 01,02,…,09,10,11,…